# FS_ACCESS error when trying to exchange certificates with Pocophone F1 (and android emulators)

Tags: react-native, debugging, flipper, fbflipper

I've been using flipper to debug react-native for a while now, out of the blue it started giving me errors and pluggins cannto connect to flipper anymore

I have also raised an [issue](https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/5470) to the github team of flipper about my problem, but with not any help yet

Generally i have tried installing flipepr from scratch again, with all teh steps done correctly, but no different outcome.
Any help would be apreciated

Common react-native deugging with flipper, was working fine until it wasn't
Expected: Network and the rest of flipper pluggins should normally connect to flipepr as they did before